# JS: uncheck box when another is checked but also uncheck itself if checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have three checkboxes. I am already using a piece of code I found here to uncheck the other two when one is checked.

```
function cbChange(obj) {
var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("cb");
for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
    cbs[i].checked = false;
}
obj.checked = true;
}
```

I use this inside the checkbox to toggle the state: onchange="cbChange(this)".

However, I also need to provide for a situation where I don't want any of the boxes ticked. While I can do this by adding a separate button or checkbox, I wanted to know if the above code can be modified or another function added that will allow to untick the already ticked box by an onclick event.

I tried adding this function (again found here) but it won't work:

```
function cbUncheck(obj)
    {
        if (obj.checked == false)
        {
            document.getElementByClassName("cb").checked = false;
        }
    }
```

I use this in the checkbox code: onclick="cbUncheck(this);"

Suggestions welcome!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you thinking of your end users?  If I check a box that unchecks itself so fast that I don't notice, then I think something is wrong.  This is a question where the answer is, "Yes, you *can* do it, but that doesn't mean you should."

Comment: Isn't this what radio buttons are for?

Comment: @Jeremy Miller: I don't think this is a problem in my case.

Comment: @RobG: Radio buttons cannot be cleared, if the user wants none of the options selected unless an additional button is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check first checkbox checked or not..
if checkbox is not checked then dont need to do anything
otherwise uncheck other checkboxes

```
 <input id="chk1" class="cb" type="checkbox" value="01" onchange='cbChange(this)' />
  <label for="chk1" >1</label>


  <input id="chk2" class="cb" type="checkbox" value="01" onchange='cbChange(this)' />
  <label for="chk2" >1</label>


  <input id="chk3" class="cb" type="checkbox" value="01" onchange='cbChange(this)' />
  <label for="chk3" >1</label>
```

javascript

```
function cbChange(obj) {

  if(obj.checked)
  {

     var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("cb");
     for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
        cbs[i].checked = false;
        }
      obj.checked = true;
   }
}
```

JS BIN [JSBIN EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/tohiyabe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use radio buttons so that only one can be selected (no script required for that). Then if some other condition occurs, clear both (below uses a button as an example):

```
<form>
  <input  type="radio" name="foo" value="0">zero<br>
  <input  type="radio" name="foo" value="1">one<br>
  <button type="button" onclick="clearRadios(this.form.foo)">Clear radios</button>
</form>
```

And the function:

```
function clearRadios(radioGroup) {
  for (var i=0; i<radioGroup.length; i++) {
    radioGroup[i].checked = false;
  }
}
```

If you don't want users to check the radios at all, disable them.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use radio buttons - or, rather, I don't want to add an extra button to clear the selected radio button.

Answer (score 0):

This below code simply give solutions to what you need.

```
 this.scan=function(index)
 {
  if( this.boxGroup[ index ].checked )
   for(var i=0, g=this.boxGroup, len=g.length; i<len; i++)
    if( i != index )
     g[i].checked = false;
 }
```

for working demo see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mz7pU/)

Comment: Thanks, I see it is working and this is exactly the way I want it to be. However, I can't get it to work on my page because each of the checkboxes has a different name in my case, and in your script they all use the same name. My JS knowledge is too little to be able to modify it for my case.

Comment: Please disregard the above comment. The names are the same. I still can't get it to work, however. The problem is that more than one checkbox can be selected. The only change I've made to the code as given in jsfiddle is the form and checkbox names:
    new Cb2Rb( document.forms.searchform.searchtype );

Here is the page in question: http://dictionary.asphodel-works.com/

Comment: Because I decided to use the code proposed by GujjuDeveloper below, I uploaded a newer version of the file. Here is a version of the page with your code: http://dictionary.asphodel-works.com/index1.php